# Iframe re-renders inside itself automatically

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have a very simple react component that only has an iframe, and I've just put the borders to make sure that it's visible.

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div>
       <iframe title="item" src=""  width={500} height={500} style={{border: '5px solid red', overflowClipMargin: 'contentBox', overflow: 'clip'}}></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, if I put the src set as below, iframe keeps reloading inside itself and never actually loads the content, causing the iframe to be filled red.

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div>
       <iframe title="item" src="./assets/tester"  width={500} height={500} style={{border: '5px solid red', overflowClipMargin: 'contentBox', overflow: 'clip'}}></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpOlr.png) What it looks like after a few seconds

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPAey.png) After a few more seconds

When I tested iframe in pure html, it was working perfectly fine, but I don't know what is going on with react. I've also tried to debug why it's reloading with browser extension, but it only says that the App was re-rendered by its parent component.